# Status of jquery.ajax from Server-Side Javascript

Tags: marketing-cloud, jquery, ajax, ssjs

Please see the following codes:

1. Front-side AJAX request code:

   ```
   function addAjax(emailIds, valObj) {
       var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
       method: "post",
       url: "mypage.aspx?QS=38dfbe491fab00ea43dd19ab5b52eaf2bbc7695cbeb323600f48c357090984b3",
       data: {emailIds: emailIds, methodName: "deleteMapDE"},
       }).done(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       }).fail(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       }).always(function() {
           //Some code.
       });
   ```

   }
2. Server-side JavaScript code to delete data extension:

   ```
   Platform.Load("Core","1");
   var methodName = Request.GetFormField("methodName");

   if ("deleteMapDE" === methodName) {
       deleteMapDE();
   } else {

   }

   function deleteMapDE() {
       var emailIds = Request.GetFormField("emailIds");
       var arrayEmailIds = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(emailIds);
       for (var i = 0; i < arrayEmailIds.length; i++) {
           Platform.Function.DeleteData("Map Tags With Emails", ["Email ID"], [arrayEmailIds[i]]);
       }
   }
   ```

So, my question is: why the client side always return result from `.fail()` regardless of whether server-side executed properly?

I thought the question is neither not from `Jquery.ajax()` nor Server-Side JavaScript, so what`s the problem from?

Comment: Can you check what status codes you are getting?

Comment: yes, I checked. I`m just wondering on it, because the returned status is: 200, 'readystatus' is: 4, that`s mean operation is done properly.

Comment: What is the doctype of your landing page?  It would need to be set to JSON in order for jquey to parse the response correctly.  If you do not see JSON as a doctype option, you may need to contact support to have it enabled.

Comment: The front-side doctype is web page and the server-side is json.